# LET and SETF in commonLISP

Tags: let, clisp, setf

From what my teacher told me, I should use let to declare local variables and setf to declare global variables.

I'm tried running the following code:

```
(let (state-list (problem-initial-state problem))
  (print state-list))
```

and I get NIL.

However, when I try the following:

```
(setf state-list (problem-initial-state problem))
  (print final-list)
```

I get the desired value (the value in problem-initial-state problem).

Why is that?

PS: I apologize for these begginer questions, I'm getting a hard time getting into LISP, coming from a C background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a couple of parens in your [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) forms:

```
(let ((a 1)
      (b 2))
  (print (list a b)))
```

will print `(1 2)`.

Your form

```
(let (state-list (problem-initial-state problem))
  (print state-list))
```

binds `state-list` to `nil` and `problem-initial-state` to `problem`.